# Collection View not displaying properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nscollectionview

i'm having a collection view , segment control and a arraycontroller. i used `setFilterPredicate:` method to filter the data based on the segment pressed and displayed in collectionView.  what my problem was the filtered data displayed in collectinview but the loactions were misplaced.[image]

can you see that collection items were displayed at the middle of the collection view?
how can i bring them to front?

Comment: show your collectionview code

Comment: Nope, see your delegate & datasource method of Collectionviw

Comment: i subclassed collectionViewItem .then binded arraycontroller and collectionview.

Comment: i got proper collectionview before adding following code..               ` [arrayController removeObjects:[arrayController arrangedObjects]];
  [arrayController addObjects:mainArray];
  [arrayController setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate                                                            predicateWithFormat:@"Status == 'favorite'"]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used  `[arrayController removeObjects:[arrayController content]];` instead of `[arrayController removeObjects:[arrayController arrangedObjects]];`. i just replaced arranged objects to content.